# Is every quotient algebra of a Boolean algebra isomorphic to a subalgebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Is every (non-trivial) quotient of a Boolean algebra isomorphic to a subalgebra of that Boolean algebra? And conversely is every subalgebra isomorphic to a quotient algebra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is no, there are quotient algebras that cannot be embedded as subalgebras. Let's take $\newcommand{\powerset}{\mathcal{P}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}A = \powerset(\N)$, the ideal $I \subseteq A$ to be the set of finite subsets, and $B = A/I$. We need to show that $B$ is not a subalgebra of $A$.

We start by observing that $A$ has what is known as the *countable chain condition*, which is that if $(S_i)_{i \in I}$ is a pairwise disjoint family of non-zero elements of $A$, then $I$ is countable. This follows from the countability of $\N$.

We can therefore show that $B$ is not a subalgebra of $A$ by finding an uncountable pairwise disjoint family in $B$. We do this as follows. For each $n \in \N$, we write $\mathbf{digits}(n)$ for the finite sequence expressing $n$ in binary. For each infinite binary sequence $a \in 2^\N$, define $S_a \subseteq \N$ as:
$$
S_a = \{ n \in \N \mid \mathbf{digits}(n) \text{ is a prefix of } a\}
$$
As is well known, $2^\N$ is uncountable. Each $S_a$ is infinite, because each finite prefix of $a$ comes from some $n \in \N$, so the equivalence class $[S_a]$ is non-zero in $B$. Finally, if $a \neq b$ are elements of $2^\N$, they have only finitely many prefixes that are the same, so $S_a \cap S_b$ is finite, so the equivalence classes $[S_a]$ and $[S_b]$ are disjoint in $B$. So we have shown that $([S_a])_{a \in 2^\N}$ is an uncountable disjoint family in $B$, which would be a contradiction if $B$ could be embedded as a subalgebra of $A$.

---

For your second question, the answer is also no, there are subalgebras that are not isomorphic to any quotient. However, I was not able to make this example as elementary as the other one, so I will be using Stone duality and a bit of general topology.

Let's start again with $A = \powerset(\N)$, and define the subalgebra $B$ to consist of finite sets and *cofinite* sets, *i.e.* complements of finite sets. Assume for a contradiction that $B$ is representable as a quotient of $A$, so there is a surjective Boolean homomorphism $f : A \rightarrow B$. The Stone space of $A$ is $\beta \N$, the Stone-Čech compactification of $\N$, and the Stone space of $B$ is the "free convergent sequence", *i.e.* it is homeomorphic to the subspace $S = \{ 0, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n}, \cdots \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The Stone dual of $f$ is a continuous injective map $g : S \rightarrow \beta(X)$. But as $\beta(X)$ is extremally disconnected, every convergent sequence is eventually constant, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. (By the way, shouldn't it be called the countable *anti*chain condition? Is that standard terminology?)

Comment: The standard terminology is "countable chain condition" or "c.c.c.", even though it's about antichains (and therefore can mislead the newcomer). From time to time some people try to change it to "countable antichain condition" or "c.a.c." but this never seems to catch on.

Answer (score 1):

This question gets right to the inner workings of Boolean algebras so I'm surprised nobody has answered it. I don't know the answer in general and would love to see a proof of a positive answer, or a counterexample!

For what it's worth I think I can show the answer is "yes" in both directions for *finite* Boolean algebras, and that something stronger than isomorphism holds. If $A$ is a Boolean algebra, and $Q$ is a quotient algebra of $A$ by some ideal, and $S$ is a subalgebra of $A$, let us say, for lack of a better word, that $Q$ "subsumes" $S$ when each $Q$-element (which is of course an equivalence class of $A$-elements) has exactly one element from $S$. If $Q$ subsumes $S$, the map taking each $Q$-member to its respective $S$-member is a (boolean) isomorphism onto $S$.

Claim: when $A$ is finite, every quotient algebra $Q$ subsumes some subalgebra $S$, and conversely every $S$ is subsumed by some $Q$.

First note that any finite boolean algebra $A$ is isomorphic to the power set of its atoms: the function mapping each $p \in A$ to the set of atoms $\leq p$ is a bijection, and the boolean operations on $A$ agree respectively with union, intersection, and complement on the power set of $A$'s atoms. Thus the finite boolean algebras can be characterized up to isomorphism as $\mathcal{P}(\{1, ..., n\})$ where $n$ can be any natural number $> 0$. (I am ignoring the one-element "degenerate" algebra.)

Second, note that a subalgebra of $\mathcal{P}(\{1,...,n\})$ is uniquely determined by its atoms, which together necessarily form a partition of $\{1,...,n\}$; and any such partition can serve as atoms for a subalgebra. A quotient of $\mathcal{P}(\{1,...,n\})$ by a nontrivial ideal is uniquely determined by that ideal's greatest element, which can be any nonempty subset of $\{1,...,n\}$.

Now let $Q$ be the quotient of $\mathcal{P}(\{1,...,n\})$ by some given ideal, which by the preceding paragraph must have a greatest element which can by any  nonempty subset $X \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$. Let $Z$ be any partition of $\{1,...,n\}$ such that each $e \in Z$ has exactly one member that is not in $X$. Then I think it should be easy to show that $Z$ is the set of atoms of a subalgebra $S$ that is subsumed by $Q$. Note that since $Z$ need not be unique in general for a given $Q$, $S$ need not be unique in general.

Conversely, when $S$ is any subalgebra of $\mathcal{P}(\{1,...,n\})$, and $Z$ is its set of atoms (which again can be any partition of $\{1,...,n\}$), let $X$ be any subset of $\{1,...,n\}$ such that for all $e \in Z$, $|X \cap e| = |e| - 1$. Then when $Q$ is the quotient by the ideal whose greatest element is $X$, $Q$ subsumes $S$.